# mosquittopp: publish message to broker

Tags: c++, c, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using cpp wrapper for mosquitto under linux.
After initializing:

```
this->keepalive = 60;   
this->id = id;
this->port = port;
this->host = host;
this->topic = topic;
mosquittopp::log_init(MOSQ_LOG_ALL, MOSQ_LOG_STDOUT);
const int result = connect(host, port, keepalive);
```

how can I publish my custom message?

I'm using publish method defined by wrapper in this way:

```
int publish(uint16_t *mid, const char *topic, uint32_t payloadlen=0, const uint8_t *payload=NULL, int qos=0, bool retain=false);
```

So I can call in this way:

```
publish(NULL, topic, strlen(message));
```

but.. where I can specify the real "message"?

Comment: From the mosquitto documentation:

" payload: pointer to the data to send. If payloadlen > 0 this must be a valid memory location. "

I'd say `payload` must be a pointer to a valid string of `payloadlen` size.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can fine sample code for a publishing example in c++ http://www.disk91.com/2013/technology/programming/mosquitto-c-sample-code-to-publish-message/

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as,

```
publish(NULL, topic, strlen(message), message);
```

for have an idea,[taken from mosquitto example temp_conv]

```
temp_farenheit = temp_celsius*9.0/5.0 + 32.0;
snprintf(buf, 50, "%f\n", temp_farenheit);
publish(NULL, "temperature/celsius", strlen(buf), buf);
```